# v-mask not working correctly with veutifyjs input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using veutifyjs text-input to show phone number. I have a button to assign phone number to v-model. But after assign it not change there text input. if I enter some think on text-input v-mask work. But if I assign value to v-model it not working. Also i'm tying next trick but its not have any difference.

```
 <v-text-field
          v-model="form.phone_number"
          v-mask="'(###) ###-####'"
          dense
          outlined
          autocomplete="new-password"
          hide-details="auto"
          label="Phone Number"
          placeholder="Phone Number"
        ></v-text-field>

   <v-btn color="warning" @click="dataupdate()">Add</v-btn>
```

```
dataupdate() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.form.phone_number = '4032223344'
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `v-mask` dynamically after you set the value of `form.phone_number`, so we could create a `phoneNumberMask` variable:

```
data() {
  return {
    phoneNumberMask: '',
  };
}
```

Set it as the `v-mask` value:

```
 <v-text-field
          v-model="form.phone_number"
          v-mask="phoneNumberMask"
...
```

then at `dataupdate()`:

```
dataupdate() {
      this.form.phone_number = '4032223344'
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.phoneNumberMask = '(###) ###-####'
      })
      /*
       * you'd just have to deal with calling this function
       * when phoneNumberMask already has a value
       * and that depends on your business rules
       */
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply your solution is working but my component on inside <keep-alive>. If I remove <keep-alive> its work. But with <keep-alive> isn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after migration to Vuetify 2 and fixed it so: Just replaced `v-mask` library with [`vue-input-facade`](https://github.com/RonaldJerez/vue-input-facade) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10920).

It works exactly the same as the old `mask` from the first Vuetify but you should use the parameter "`v-facade`" instead.

Comment: Thank you! v-facade works with Vuetify 2 v-text-field

Answer (score 0):

I my case, i use this soluction and solved my problem

the method:

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  @input="inputValue"
  @paste="pasteValue"
  v-mask="phoneNumberMask"
  v-model="tel"
  :required="required"
  aria-label
  aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
  :disabled="disabled"
/>
pasteValue(e) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  this.tel = '';
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.tel = e.target.value;
  }, 100);
}
```